# No database selected on PHP MySQL

Tags: php

> Error: No Database Selected

I have a website that was hosted with ARVIXE (windows 2008 server) and presently with IXWEBHOSTING (windows 2003 server). It was very simple to move. It was a matter to just download/upload the site PHP files and export/import MySQL database and change the config PHP file to point to the new 
database information and voila!

Now I am trying to move the site to my own server. Trust me I have no problems with DNS, servers, networking stuff. I've being doing this for 15 years (not programming).
This is my actual server: Windows 2003 STD SP2, IIS6, PHP5.2.12, MySQL 5.0.96, FastCGI 1.5. and all MS Updates.

Now here me out before you conclude that is the code or MySQL permissions... I have read I think all the No Database Selected errors on the Internet including here and is usually a little code modification or missing code or permission issue on the database...but not this one, see the scenarios below and you will see why not.

- **Scenario 1**
  PHP Files are sitting in the IXWEBHOSTING servers. The config PHP file points to my own MySQL server it works fine.
- **Scenario 2**
  PHP Files are sitting in the IXWEBHOSTING servers. The config PHP file points to IXWEBHOSTING MySQL server it works fine.
- **Scenario 3**
  PHP Files are sitting in my Win2k3 servers. The config PHP file points to IXWEBHOSTING MySQL server, I get error "No database selected".
- **scenario 4**
  PHP Files are sitting in my Win2k3 servers. The config PHP file points to my own MySQL server, I get error "No database selected".

So I know for a fact it has nothing to do with MySQL permission on my own MySQL server or PHO code as scenario 1 proves it. It seems to be a problem with PHP on my server.

Prior of installing the OLD PHP and MySQ, I had the lastest version of each PHP 5.3.13 and MySQL 5.5.25 and same FastCGI version. I had the exact same problem!!!! The reason why I installed the old versions is because I wanted to match IXWEBHOSTING server versions.

Prior to the above installations, Windows was installed from scratch each time on a hyper-v server. No updates MS updates were done on the server the first attemps and the last installation it has all the MS updates and I still have the same problem.

I had the same problem with Windows 2008 STD, PHP 5.3.13 and MySQL 5.5.25.

PHP is loading all the proper extensions to make the connections to MySQL. I also have PHPmyAdmin running without problems.

I also tried with in the config file and no luck

There is a lot of stuff in the index but this is what is needed to make the connection to the database and the query and where it fails.

**config file**

```
<?
$usuarios_sesion="youth";
$host="localhost";
$user="usernamehere";
$pass="passwordhere";        
$db="databasehere";
$tabla="users";
?>
```

**Index.php File**

```
<?
require ("enlaces_config.inc.php");

$menu=mysql_query("SELECT id_cat, name_cat FROM categories WHERE access=0 AND published=1") or die ("Can't select categorias MySQL says: ".mysql_error());

?>
```

At this point I have no idea what else it can be... permissions, maybe but not in MySQL permission, the user has full priviledges to the database. Scenario 1 and 2 proves it too.

If you need to check PHP information let me know. I will post the name of the php file for excution

Help!

Comment: While you should be moving away from the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, the error is clear, and you'll need to select a DB: [`mysql_select_db($db)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php). If you aren't connected, `mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with all that you have written w.r.t your server.
When you try to fetch data from a database you must essentially follow these steps-

1. Create a connection

   That involves connecting using Database, User Name, and Password, along with Hostname. You can use `mysql_connect()`, although *deprecated*.
2. You need to select the database from that host.
3. You go for any mysql query using selected db connection in step 2.

I would suggest you to get a good grip on database concepts first and then implementation using php.

Best place to start http://w3schools.com